# Square number yes or no?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

my Problem is the following. $a$ and $b$ are positive integers and are there $x$ and $y$ so that $a+b, a+2b$ and $2a+b$ are all square numbers?

Every suggestion is desired. Thanks.

Comment: What role do x and y have on your question ?

Comment: I'm wondering that, too. Kind of like a computer program that declares variables it never uses.

Comment: It is interesting to generalize the task. When $a+b , ka+b , a+kb $     all the squares. For which values of $k$ there are solutions?

Answer (score 2):

$a+b=m^2, a+2b=n^2, b+2a=p^2 \to 3(a+b) = n^2+p^2 \to n^2+p^2=3m^2$, this means $3|(n^2+p^2)$, and $3|n$, and $3|p$. Thus: $n=3r$, $p=3t$, and $9r^2+9t^2 = 3m^2 \to 3(r^2+t^2)=m^2$, and $3|m$, so again $m=3k$. Thus: $r^2+t^2=3k^2$. By the descend method, we must have that $m=n=p=0$ as the only integer solution, but since they are positive integers, we conclude that the original system of equations has no solutions.

Answer (score 0):

For the system of equations:

$$\left\{\begin{aligned}&a+b=z^2\\&ka+b=x^2\\&a+kb=y^2\end{aligned}\right.$$

If you can the amount be represented as a sum of squares: $k+1=t^2+n^2$

Then the solution can be written:

$$z=p^2+s^2$$

$$x=np^2+2tps-ns^2$$

$$y=-tp^2+2nps+ts^2$$

$$a=\frac{x^2-z^2}{k-1}$$

$$b=\frac{kz^2-x^2}{k-1}$$

$p,s$ - integers asked us.